# Where is the .phtml to modify category page filters?

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, frontend

Good afternoon,

I have a question, where is the .phtml to modify category page filters (frontend)?

[image]

I don´t find the file and I need this to modify the words *Filter by*.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

check out this handy tool to handle exactly these cases where you don't know where to look.

https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_DevTools

Cheers